# Convert TCHAR* to QString

Tags: qt, type-conversion, qt5

How to convert easiest way in Qt?

```
int recordSize = 1000;
TCHAR* qRecord = new TCHAR[recordSize];
//here I get data form other function
//here I try to display
qString() << QString::fromWCharArray(qRecord,recordSize);//gives many ????
printf("%s",qRecord); // this work perfectly
```

I tried with wcstombs, formStdWString nad other but nothing seems to work.
Thanks for any help

Comment: and with `QString::fromLocal8Bit`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 QString s= (LPSTR)qRecord;
```

worked.
thanks

Answer (score 7):

@kajojeq
no, your second  answer is not correct.  because when the encoding is set to utf16(or even utf8 sometimes) the s variable only save one character.
correct conversion is:

QString str =  QString::fromWCharArray(qrecord)

Comment: this should be the accepted answer because these days encodings are set to UT8 or UT16 by default. As Rashid mentions, the accepted solution does not work at all then. The answer that Rashid provided works correctly in the case of UT8/16